# Correlation in Excel using Data analysis add-in with a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dataset, correlation, excel-addins

I am trying to find the correlation for several columns at a time. I have used data analysis add-in and I want to apply a condition to go with. for example, my worksheet have data about clients having paying difficulties and clients with no payment difficulties. so,by using data analysis toolpak I am getting correlation of entire data but i want to get the correlation for clients with payment difficulties only. I have tried to use =correl() with nested if function
=CORREL(IF (Table13[TARGET]=Correlations!$B$4,Cleaned_data!$H$2:$H$50000), IF(Table13[TARGET]=Correlations!$B$4,Cleaned_data!$G$2:$G$50000)). It gives the correct correlation but i have manually enter this formula for each row. Is there any way to automate this process?

excepting to automate the process

Comment: Can you gives us an idea of the data layout?

Comment: Please use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table or use this [website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to create a Markdown table.

Comment: Welcome Mounika! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!